# execute SetTimeout or $timeout only on some action

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I trigger either setTimeout or $timeout on a button click. Right now even if I put it inside the button click function it getting executed on its own it is not waiting for the click event to trigger it.

```
$scope.btnClick = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.close();
        }, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: From what I understand, you've got a button like follows: `<button ng-click="btnClick()"></button>` and you've got that function in the controller that button is in. That might not be right, could you clarify in the question?

Comment: do you want to call this function after the `onclick` event of jquery gets fired?

Answer (score 2):

use $timeout instead of setTimeout and use $scope.$apply() in your "$scope.close()" function.

Note: If you want to see the changes in UI , You may use $scope.$apply() in your function. using console.log() doesn't prove it words properly ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.btnClick = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.close();
        }, 1000)
    };
    $scope.close = function(){
      console.log("done");
    };
}]);

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="btnClick()">Do</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is a snippet with timeout working.
Here is the plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/7ZS5TTnCb50nbgBuXqj1?p=preview